# FTP upload fails if using a browser

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to share large photo files from a relative using FTP to my web site (Linux hosted). I create a folder there for them with a user password. And it works fine using Win7 Windows Explorer to log in with FTP and drag and drop to upload files to the server (so it seems not a permissions issue). However getting two Windows Explorer instances up for drag and drop seems a technical issue for non-computer-aware relatives. Using a browser would make explaining easier. My notion is that a browser should work.

But the problem I cannot solve is that FTP upload (drag and drop) will not work with either the current Chrome or Firefox browsers. The browser can log in, and can download files, everything works except upload, but upload fails. Upload attempt seems to blow FTP away on the host, when then any other (separate and normal) server FTP access is ignored until a couple of minutes of timeout. No errors shown. The host FTP log just stops, does not mention the failure. This failure occurs using Frontier FiOS connection from my home, in Win7. All other FTP has always worked well.

Again, browser log on and download does work, and upload does work if instead using two instances of Windows Explorer.

Can anyone mention any further requirement for a browser to be able to upload files to a FTP web host? Thanks.